# Understanding why NYBC will show profits next year

Tags: stocks

I'm reading this article, [How NYCB Is Trying to Right the Ship, After Downgrades and Selloff](https://www.barrons.com/articles/nycb-bank-stock-price-news-moodys-debt-downgrade-39ae2adc), and quote:

> Sticking with a Buy rating amid the panic is Piper Sandler’s Mark Fitzgibbon. Deposits have grown since December, he noted Wednesday, and the bank’s $37 billion in liquidity is over 160% of uninsured deposits. It will show profits this year and the next.

I do not understand why `the bank’s $37 billion in liquidity is over 160% of uninsured deposits` is an indicator of profits next year?

Comment: If they haven't substantiated that claim it's a guess. Maybe an educated guess, maybe not, maybe they're just trying to pump the price up before unloading their own shares. Take all such claims as a guess at best.

Comment: The article isn't saying that the bank will show profits this year and next because of its liquidity.  It is making three completely separate points.  First, deposits have grown since December.  Second, the bank has liquidity in excess of uninsured deposits.  Third, the bank is still profitable.  Each of those factors (assuming they are true) increases the probability that the bank will survive rather than fail.